# Rearranging Indicators (Dropbox, Clementine and Recent Notifications)

Tags: 12.10, indicator

Here are my indicators on the top bar.
[image: indicators]

{From left to right, first one is Free Rapid Downloader and second is Recent Notifications (jconti)}

I have managed to reorder some of them using the file

> /usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile

```
[Ordering Index Overrides]
nm-applet=1
gnome-power-manager=2
ibus=3
gst-keyboard-xkb=4
gsd-keyboard-xkb=5
indicator-sensors=6
indicator-cpufreq=7
jupiter-client=8
classicmenu-indicator=9
caffeine-cup-empty=10
multiload=12
```

I would now like to place multiload on the complete left. 
I.E move Dropbox, Clementine and Recent Notifications(jconti) right
I do not need to move Free Rapid Downloader and I've changed default icons of recent notifications.

What are the names of the dropbox indicator, clementine indicator and recent notifications indicator to be used in the ordering-override.keyfile ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The names of the indicators can be found out with:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=com.canonical.indicator.application /com/canonical/indicator/application/service com.canonical.indicator.application.service.GetApplications | grep "object path"
```

Replace underscores with hyphens in the keyfile.

Source: http://www.acetous.de/179/ubuntu-12-04-finetuning