# Top right icons messed up Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Tags: unity, 13.04, icons

First time posting a question here so if I fail, please excuse me and of course notify me about my mistake.

My situation is that currently I'm on holiday in Spain and I installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside my Windows 8 install.

Both are 64 bit and my Ubuntu also has 32bit libs installed for convenience and running programs like XAMPP for Linux etc.

So my issue is not really big or very interesting but it bugs me...

When I first logged in, all the icons in the top right (e.g. login / WiFi / Ubuntu One / sound / power) were all nicely lined up how they are supposed to be.

**HOWEVER** the second time I logged in... the **Power** icon was somewhere in-between.

[image]

I am not an experienced Linux user but I do use it for speed and ease of use (hence Ubuntu) and I know my way a little with the sudoing but nothing special.

The only thing I really want is the power button most right.

However, I have no clue how to fix this.

Any help would be much appreciated and sorry for the probably 'stupid' question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the order of Unity Application Indicators for all users in `/usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile` file:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile
```

If you only want to change the order only for current user, (create and) edit this file:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/indicators/application/ordering-override.keyfile
```

Source: http://ubuntuguide.net/change-order-of-unity-application-indicators-in-ubuntu-12-04

To get the proper name to use in the keyfile, see https://askubuntu.com/a/259198/20835

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch, I did thoroughly search for a solution to later find out it was actually called an indicator bar... So I was stumped and still feeling quite stupid, however I had to do a reinstall anyways due to a reboot gone bad. Anyways I'm back up and running! But thanks for the answer tho, I eventually found the same and checked back to complete this, once again sorry for the duplicate and stupidity :<