# Change order of electron tray icons

Tags: unity, indicator, electron

A few questions regarding ordering of the tray icons already have been asked (see [here for example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240297/rearranging-indicators-dropbox-clementine-and-recent-notifications)). This usually works great, electron apps behave somehow differently. When running an electron app (e.g. whatsie, gitter or Franz) the command

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=com.canonical.indicator.application /com/canonical/indicator/application/service com.canonical.indicator.application.service.GetApplications | grep "object path"
```

yields

```
object path /org/ayatana/NotificationItem/D9C91CA1_0092_45B8_9F09_108CB12987B3/Menu"
```

for the running electron app. The number `D9C91CA1_0092_45B8_9F09_108CB12987B3` changes every time the app starts. Is there some structure behind that number which I can use to change `ordering-override.keyfile` before the app starts? (Dropbox has a similar problem, but there are ways to fix this)

Comment: While Dropbox case is similar, it's not the same (if you mean the fix like [that](http://askubuntu.com/a/506982/123714) ). Dropbox produces the object path which contains `dropbox` string in it, so it can be proceeded by grep, sed, etc. In the case of Electron the ID string is rather meaningless and contains no distinctive keywords to separate it from others.

Comment: But the ID string has to come from somewhere, right?

Comment: Have you tried to find this ID string among the list of processes with `ps -ef | grep D9C91CA1_0092_45B8_9F09_108CB12987B3` (change the ID appropriately in your current session)?

Comment: Ok it really is a random number: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/lkcr/base/guid.h  (line 24). Still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The single method of arranging icons in the tray (known to me) is to use the override file. If this ID was among the list of processes, it was possible to extract it (e.g.: `grep -Eo '[A-F0-9]{8}_[A-F0-9]{4}_[A-F0-9]{4}_[A-F0-9]{4}_[A-F0-9]{12}'`) and reuse it in modified script for Dropbox. Otherwise I dunno how this can be achieved. **BTW**, what's the relation of the Chromium source code to Electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this was a bug with electron I created an [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5969) on github and also proposed a [pull request](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/5988).

If the Pull request gets merged this issue should be solved.